# How to deploy an angular app into SharePoint classic site?

Tags: angular, deployment, sharepoint-online, web-parts

I have an angular app basically a chatbot that I would like to embed into a SharePoint classic site. I need inputs on how to accomplish the task. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the SharePoint Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) or Script Editor Web Part?

If yes, then that can be done by embedding your angular app.

1. You'll need to host your Angular app somewhere accessible.
2. Once your Angular app is hosted and accessible via a URL, you'll need to get the embeddable code.
3. Embed in SharePoint Classic Site using CEWP or Script Editor webpart.

Make sure that the users who are accessing the SharePoint site also have permission to access your angular app as well.